# How to make directory to be created with defined usergroup if we do mapping on same directory twice

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, rpm-spec, rpm-maven-plugin

In my pom.xml

```
 <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.1</version>
 <goal>rpm</goal>
...
 <mapping>
          <directory>/etc/conf</directory>
          <username>ME</username>
          <groupname>ME</groupname>

          <sources>
            <source>
              <location>../install.properties</location>
            </source>
          </sources>
</mapping>
```

...

When use  the above `/etc/conf` folder get created with `ME:ME` permission.

```
         <mapping>
              <directory>/etc/conf</directory>
              <username>ME</username>
              <groupname>ME</groupname>
              <sources>
                <source>
                  <location>../install.properties</location>
                </source>
              </sources>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
              <directory>/etc/conf</directory>
              <username>ME</username>
              <groupname>ME</groupname>
              <sources>
                <source>
                  <location>../install2.properties</location>
                </source>
              </sources>
    </mapping>
```

But when i add another mapping the `/etc/conf` folder gets created with `root:root`

What am i missing ?

Comment: First try to use an up-to-date version of the [rpm-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/) which is currently 2.1-alpha-3.

Comment: @khmarbaise Tried with latest version... but same result.. please take a look at the updated question..

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says :

```
directoryIncluded
If the value is true then the attribute string will be written for the directory 
if the sources identify all of the files in the directory 
(that is, no other mapping contributed files to the directory). 
This is the default behavior.
```

Since in this case there are two mapping contributing to same directory therefore `%attr` will not be written for the directory in the spec file.
We might need to include one more mapping like:

```
    <mapping>
              <directory>/etc/conf</directory>
              <username>ME</username>
              <groupname>ME</groupname>

    </mapping>
```

Comment: And all of the mappings should explicitly set the directoryIncluded config value. The mapping that is just to control ownership of the directory should set to true and the other mappings providing content should set it to false.